# Can the Einstein Field Equations be written as Functional Equations?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-equations

I'm interested in describing physical systems with algebraic equations as opposed to differential equations. In an earlier Phys.SE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/279170/2451) I gave an example - the Simple Harmonic Oscillator can be described by the functional equation:

$$f(n) = kf(n-1) - f(n-2)$$

where $n=2,3,4,5,..$ and $k$ is a constant.

But that's a simple system, what about a far more complex system? Can the EFE (Einstein Field Equations) be written as a set of functional equations?

Comment: Hi. That's an interesting question. I think the SHO works because it's essentially a simple ODE. However, the field equations are tensor equations. When you "solve" the Einstein equations, you are solving for a metric tensor, of which there are potentially 10 independent components in 4-dimensions. Then, there is the additional problem that in G.R., the governing equations are not just Einstein's equations, they are also the Killing equations as well. But, your question is interesting, and will require some more thought on my part! :)

Comment: @Dr.IkjyotSinghKohli You say, "in G.R., the governing equations are not just Einstein's equations, they are also the Killing equations as well". I have never heard of this. Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @Ken Abbott: Comment to the post (v5): What definition of [functional equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation) do you use? Are you talking about a _discretization_ of the EFE? Or perhaps _algebraic equations?_

Comment: Well, the Ricci tensor is built up on the metric tensor. Assuming vacuum equations $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$ and substituting the components of the metric, you could say the metric is a matrix whose components satisfy the functional equation $R_{\mu\nu} = 0$? I'm no mathematician btw and this is just idle musing on my part.

Comment: @Qmechanic - By functional equation I mean a function define implicitly i.e. in terms of itself. In general this does not imply discretization, for example.. a body falling under (newtonian) gravity is ruled by the functional equation.. f(2t) = 4f(t) where f is the distance fallen in time t. However, functions of an integer variable (discretization) are clearly a subset of functional equations.

Answer (score 2):

First, these are not functional equations, but discretized differential equations or difference equations.

What stops you from taking Einstein's equations and plugging a difference operator everywhere where a partial derivative occurs?

If you want to preserve manifest general covariance, I suggest looking in the direction of [Regge calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regge_calculus). It is based on splitting of the $n$-dimensional spacetime manifold in $n$-simplices and considering its triangulation. I suppose you are most interested in $n=4$ case.

A 4-simplex also known as pentachoron is a full graph with 5 vertices. Its sides are 3-simplices aka tetrahedrons - full graphs with 4 vertices. The sides of a tetrahedron are 2-simplices aka triangles, the sides of a triangle are 1-simplices aka segments and the sides of a segment are 0-simplices aka points.

The (Euclidean) Regge action is given by

$$ S(L_s) = \sum_h A_h(L_s) \, \delta_h(L_s). $$

Here, $s$ labels the segments (1-simplices) in the triangulation. $L_s$ is the length of the segment $s$. Note that these lengths determine the geometry of the simplicial complex, just as the metric determines the geometry of the Riemannian manifold. Thus, $L_s$ are analogous to the metric field $g_{\mu \nu}$.

Also, $h$ labels *hinges* or $(n-2)$-simplices. In our case $n=4$ and hinges are triangles. $A_h$ is the $(n-2)$-volume of the hinge $h$ (the area of the triangle) and $\delta_h$ is called the deficite angle and is analogous to the curvature of the Riemannian manifold.

The equations of motions (discretized Einstein's equations or Regge equations) are given by variating the action $S(L_s)$ with respect to the lengths of segments:

$$ \sum_h \frac{\partial A_h}{\partial L_s} \, \delta_h(L_s) = 0. $$

The term with the derivative of the deficite angle vanishes analogously to the vanishing of the term with the covariant derivative of the Ricci tensor when dealing with the Einstein-Hilbert action.

It was proven by Regge that this action converges to the Einstein-Hilbert action in the continuum limit.

This construction admits generalization to higher $n$ (straightforward) and Lorentz signatures (which I don't recall, but am absolutely certain that it exists). It plays a major role in GR-based computer simulations.

Comment: Yes, the example I gave for the SHO was a difference equation. But still.. I was wondering if the EFE have ever be written as a set of functional equations?

Comment: @KenAbbott your terminology is unclear to me. What do you mean by a functional equation?

Comment: @Ken Abbott. If you mean functional programming, which is basically the ability to define functions on functions eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming I don't see why not. Even C++ and C# have some of it, and it's getting into everything. Mathematica also. Is this what you mean?

Comment: In mathematics a functional equation is one that's defined implicitly i.e. the function is defined in terms of itself. It's this "self referential" quality that interests me. My example for the SHO is a classic case.

Comment: Trivial example.. a body falling under gravity is ruled by the functional equation.. f(2t) = 4f(t) where f is the distance fallen in time t.

Comment: Ok, functional programming allows you to do those things. Also related to lambda calculus. You can use any of those languages I mentioned.

Comment: @KenAbbott your definition also admits ordinary differential equations. For example, $\lim \varepsilon^{-1} (f(x + \varepsilon) - f(x)) = f(x)$.

Comment: @BobBee WAT? This forum is about physics, this thread is labeled with tags general-relativity and differential-equations. What?.. Why?.. What are you suggesting? How is what you are suggesting related to OP's question?

Comment: @Solenodon just that functional equations can be programmed for logic or numerical solutions using functional programming. Dynamic programming is one example. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming_language#Functional_programming and see the ssmole languages and the sexton on functional programming. Yes, software, we in physics sometimes use it.

Comment: @BobBee as I am currently employed as a software developer, you can imagine that I have heard about functional programming. Please, answer this: how is this related to OP's original question? In other words, how would functional programming help you to define a system analogous to Einstein's equations? Note that I am not talking about GR-based computer simulations now, whereas functional programming languages are used for *creating software*.

Comment: It does not answer the question but it could offer related help. If I wanted to answer the question I would have. I know it does not offer the algorithms for solving the equations, you need to do that first, then figure out how to code it effectively, i.e., create the right software (to use some of your terms, sometimes it's reuse etc). Still, I am not a numerical relativity expert, so if you have any further questions just post them for the community, where you think they best belong.